# Any ideas why Restangular object value is different from the .plain() value?

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I have one Restangular object. If I update a value from this object and then, save it or print the plain() result the values are different. The .value is correct while .plain().value returned value is the old title.
Strangely, my view displays the correct updated value.

```
// Set my title value. Old value is 'Old original title'
myRestangularObject.title = 'New title';

// Get my title value, correct I get the new value.
myRestangularObject.title => 'New title'

// Get my plain title value, incorrect. Still the old value
myRestangularObject.plain().title => 'Old original title'
```

Any ideas? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I got it. I used the new beta of angular-ui/ui-router that use angular.copy on the stateParams.

The problem is that Restangular doesn't work with angular.copy ([source](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#copying-elements)):

> Before modifying an object, we sometimes want to copy it and then
> modify the copied object. We can't use angular.copy for this because
> it'll not change the this binded in the functions we add to the
> object. In this cases, you must use Restangular.copy(fromElement).